# Redirect to localhost port 38080

Tags: proxy, localhost, squid

please how can I redirect communication via squid to localhost and specific port (38080). I need something like this - from proxy.pac

`if( ( shExpMatch( url, "*.web.com*" ) || shExpMatch( url, "*.web2.com*" ) || shExpMatch( url, "*.web3.com*" ) ) ) { return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:38080"; }`

I need this setup from proxy.pac configure to squid. It is possible?

Thans for help

I try configuring squid but no success.